# Java get user choice from input string

Tags: java, string

The user has to choose which tree to use:

> Which tree would you like to test (BST, ST, RBT)?

I thought you could just take the input as a string and compare it to a string to pick which tree to use but I think im wrong, below is what ive done

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which tree would you like to test (BST, ST, RBT)? ");
    treeChoice = input.nextLine();

    if(treeChoice == "BST")
    {
        myTree = new BST<Integer>();
    }
    else if(treeChoice == "ST")
    {
        //ST<Integer> myTree = new ST<Integer>();
    }
    else if(treeChoice == "RBT")
    {
        //RBT<Integer> myTree = new RBT<Integer>();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
    }
```

That doesnt seem to be working, when i tested it the output was invalid entry.

am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(treeChoice == "BST")`

should be

`if("BST".equalsIgnoreCase(treeChoice))`

and modify the rest accordingly. The rule is do **not** use `==` for `String` comparison

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `equals` method for comparisons of two strings.
I suggest you to use switch case.
Java 7 support string in switch case.
This will improve your code readability and can handle all inputs from user.